# Substring a text since the target founded

Tags: preg-replace, substring

I have a search on my php page and it is ok.

With my search result, I highlighted the string target on my content.

```
$search_tag_text = @preg_replace("/($mysearch)/i", "<u style=\"color:red\">$1</u>", $row->txtContent);
```

Ok, but is it possible, after having found a string target on my content, to show 20 words before and 20 words after, instead listing all my content?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like:

```
$matches = array();
preg_match("/($mysearch)/i", $search_tag_text, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

And then in the match you would have the offset of where the found string is, then you could do:

```
$search_tag_text = substr($subject, ($matches[0][1] - 30), 60);
```

For 30 characters before the match and 30 after. If i've understood correctly the last element in $mathces[i][x] is the offset where the match was found.